# Edited: Callback from browser starting a new application instead of returning to the old one

Tags: android, android-asynctask, oncreate

Edit : It turns out the problem runs deeper than first expected. I just checked my processes *and it turns out that when the web browser "returns" it doesn't return to the original application proces but instead creates a new one. the result is two instances of my application running at once. How do I solve this ? This is the intent filter in my manifest I have to handle the callback*

```
<activity
       android:name=".LoginActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >

       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="whodunit" android:scheme="callback"></data>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And this is my onResume :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {  
    super.onResume();  
    if (this.getIntent()!=null && this.getIntent().getData()!=null){  
        Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();  
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith("callback://whodunit")) 
        {
            Verifier verifier = new Verifier ( uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier") );

            new OnCallBackTask(verifier).execute();
        } 

    }
    else
        new LoginTask().execute();

}
```

Comment: I think you should create singleton in `YourApp extends Application {`....

Comment: What if you make firstRun as static? private static boolean firstRun = true;

Comment: Do you mind checking out my newest edit? The problem is a different beast than first anticipated

Comment: Remove these <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
from manifest file.

Comment: The firstRun flag doesn't help because it is always will be true, if you cant use Application.class, save your flag in SharedPreferences